# System Default BooleanToVisibilityConverter not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox

I am workin on WPF application.
I am using System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter to **toggle** visibility of my **CheckBox** as follows :

```
Visibility="{Binding IsCheckVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

where IsCheckVisible is boolean property I am setting in ViewModel DataContext.

I want CheckBox to be collapsed or hidden by default when application started as my bool property will be false by default. But **problem** is it is still Visible when app is started. Plz Help me out.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: I assume BooleanToVisibilityConverter is defined as a resource.

Comment: Does IsCheckVisible raise the PropertyChanged event defined in INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem can be that you set your property `IsCheckVisible` to `false` after UI initialization. You must either support `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your ViewModel class and call `PropertyChanged` when you are changing ViewModel properties values or you can set IsCheckVisible to return `false` by default. For example:

```
private bool _isChek = false;
public bool IsCheckVisible
{
    get{ return _isCheck;}
}
```